# Mac OS keyboard shortcut to toggle two menu items

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, audio-recording

I am working on a dedicated keyboard shortcut controller for a specific app, Avid's Pro Tools. There is a default keyboard shortcut that toggles the view of two windows, "Mix" and "Edit."

Both of these commands have entries on the Window menu in the app. However, there is a little check next to the window that is active, and a little diamond next to the window that isn't. So these switch as the window is toggled (by the single keyboard shortcut).

I'm looking for a way to program a different key using the Mac OS System Application shortcuts. When I assign a new keyboard shortcut to the "Mix" and "Edit" menu items, I don't get the toggle behavior, it just causes the first item in the menu to be active. This makes sense, as it is getting two commands at once. To get the behavior I want now I have to use two keyboard shortcuts, which breaks a UI convention in Pro Tools. Any suggestions appreciated!